# Is the idea of potential energy (from physics) influenced by the idea of potentiality found in Aristotelian metaphysics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, aristotle

Aside from the common usage of the term 'potential,' was the development of the idea of potential energy influenced by the Aristotelian idea of potentiality and actuality, at least historically?

Newtonian mechanics was developed right after the medieval period which was heavily influenced by Aristotelian metaphysics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously.

> The term [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) was introduced by the 19th-century Scottish engineer and physicist [William Rankine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_John_Macquorn_Rankine).

As you can see from [Rankine's 1853 original paper](https://books.google.it/books?id=3Ov22-gFMnEC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), the author speaks of *Actual energy* and *Potential energy*.

But note that "potential energy" is not a Newtonian term : the concept of energy is not present in Newton's works.

Answer (score 2):

Heisenberg wrote in his [*Physics and Philosophy* p. 42](https://archive.org/details/HeisenbergPhysicsPhilosophy/page/n21) that the probability wave concept in quantum mechanics

> was a quantitative version of the concept of "potentia" in Aristotelian philosophy.

See also:

- "[Act, Potency, and Energy](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/2011/2011%20April/McLaughlin.pdf)" by Thomas McLaughlin, an expert in the [Aristotelian definition of motion & principle of inertia](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3904)
- [Rankine](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/William_John_Macquorn_Rankine.aspx#1)'s "[Outlines of the Science of Energetics](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outlines_of_the_Science_of_Energetics)" (which inspired [Duhem](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Pierre_Maurice_Marie_Duhem.aspx#1)'s [energetics program](https://isidore.co/calibre/#library_id=CalibreLibrary&panel=book_list&search=title:%22Trait%C3%A9%20d'%C3%A9nerg%C3%A9tique%20ou%20de%20thermodynamique%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale%22&sort=timestamp.desc))